# error with maximilienGilet/notification-bundle

Tags: symfony, notifications, bundle

This is a question answered for anyone having the same problem as I had:

Following the doc on it hub (https://github.com/maximilienGilet/notification-bundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.rst), I get the following error when using `{{ mgilet_notification_count() }}` in my template.

Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Mgilet\NotificationBundle\Twig\NotificationExtension::countNotifications() must implement interface Mgilet\NotificationBundle\NotifiableInterface, none given

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, the correct syntax in template is something like this if you want to get the notif for the current user:

```
{{ mgilet_notification_count(app.user) }}
```